# Bar graph percentages of multiple variables grouped over size

Tags: r

I would like to create a bar graph (flipped) that has the percentages of how many observations have the policy factor in place. In the bargraph all policy factors should be below each other and grouped by the size (medium or large).
Looking something like this:
[image]

Can someone please help me? I can't figure it out.

This is a snippet of my dataset:

```r
total2017 <- data.frame(
  policyfactor1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
  policyfactor2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
  policyfactor3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  policyfactor4 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
  policyfactor5 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
  policyfactor6 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L),
  policyfactor7 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  policyfactor8 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
  policyfactor9 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  size= c("medium", "medium", "large", "large", "medium", "large", "large", "medium", "large", "medium", "medium", "large", "medium", "large")
)
```

Comment: Something like 
barplot(apply(total2017[,-10],2,function(x) tapply(x,total2017[,10],sum,na.rm=TRUE)),beside=TRUE,horiz=TRUE)